# Uploading files using PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php, file, ubuntu, upload

Would you check my code please, I have given 777 permissions.

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}


else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
$path = 'var/www/html/' . $_SESSION['URL'] .'/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
if (file_exists('var/www/html/' . $_SESSION['URL'] .'/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $path);

  echo "Stored in: " . 'var/www/html/' . $_SESSION['URL'] .'/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
```

Output is:

```
Upload: lamp.odt
Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
Size: 57.5595703125 Kb
Temp file: /tmp/phpuch5Kp
path is var/www/html/man/lamp.odtStored in: var/www/html/man/lamp.odt
```

But file is not getting uploaded. It's not permission issue as I can move files in that folder.

Comment: You can see the temp file, but does it contain any data?  You said the file isn't getting uploaded... Do you mean that no data is sent, or that you can't get to its data via `$_FILES`?

Comment: where to find tmp file? My OUTPUT SAys "Temp file: /tmp/phpuch5Kp"  But there is no such file in folder TMP

File is not getting upladed means , when I check the desired folder it is empty, no file is moved to it.

Comment: fixed '/' was missing, Thanks for help guys :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can miss '/'

```
$path = '/var/www/html/' . $_SESSION['URL'] .'/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```